# angular change variable from directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i am trying to create a calendar similar to google calendar with angularJS and i got into a problem. I added the events on the screen and my html looks like this

```
<ul drop-event id="0">
    <li move-event></li>
</ul>
<ul drop-event id="1">
    <li move-event></li>
</ul>
```

.. and so on 42 boxes to show 1 month. I created a directive `drop-event` which i would like to work as droppable and also when you hover mouse on it, to get the id from the `id` of the `<ul>`. So far i did it like this

```
myApp.directive('dropEvent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                scope.theHover = elem.attr("id");
            });

            elem.droppable({ tolerance: "pointer" });

            elem.bind('drop', function(event, ui) {
                // future stuff
            });
        }
    };
});
```

but the problem is that the `theHover` variable does not change into the controller when i try to change it with `scope.theHover = elem.attr("id");` inside the directive.

And the second problem i have is that if i hover on a `<li>` which is a child to the `<ul>` , the mouseenter does not propagate to the `<ul>`.

Is there a way to make it propagate to the parent, and is there a way to change the theHover from directive into the controller ?

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're updating the variable inside a DOM event: `elem.bind('mouseenter', function() {...}` Angular doesn't know that the variable has changed.  To make it aware, wrap your code in an [`$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) like this:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
   scope.theHover = elem.attr("id");
});
```

Then your controller can watch for changes to `theHover` like this:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('theHover', function (newValue,oldValue) {
       console.log("hover ",newValue);
    });
});
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HE2s/1/)  - with the mouseenter working on the full `<ul>`